# Поменять класс у div по клику внутри этого div?

Tags: javascript

При клике по конкретному .window ему присваивается класс .opened стандартным click-addClass. Как по клику на "закрыть" убрать класс .opened у конкретного window?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cursors").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('currentz');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 mainnew2 cursors ">
  <div class="relaliv">
    <figure class="full-image-ratio ratio-1-1 zoomIn wow" data-wow-duration="0.3s" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
      <img src="<?php the_sub_field('i'); ?>">
    </figure>
    <div class="full-image-caption">
      <h4>
        <?php the_sub_field('n'); ?>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="usloviyayay">
    <div class="vertimidle">
      <h4 class="h4t">
        <?php the_sub_field('n'); ?>
      </h4>
      <p class="magi">
        <?php the_sub_field('v'); ?>
      </p>
      <div class="button-alignment">
        <a class="button-outline has-down-state losess">
          <span class="button-outline-copy small-padding">
                <span class="">
                <span class="button-text-wrapper">закрыть</span>
          </span>
          </span>
          <span class="button-outline-bottom"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: добавте чтоли свои css классы, и попытки реализовать то что нужно

Comment: К тому же не понятно. Нужен Вам ответ на чисто js или с использованием jquery. Также не понятно, упростили ли вы структуру вложенности своего `DOM` для вопроса. Или же она изначально у вас такая.

Comment: @GONG
Ответ можно и с jquery. Немного отредактировал код. Смысл в том, что есть много блоков, на которых по клику отображается контент (внутри еще несколько дивов) + кнопка закрыть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией `.closest`, которая находит ближайший указанный элемент в `DOM`

```
$('.close').click(function() {
    var nearestWindow = $(this).closest('.window');

    //возможно проверка в вашем случае будет лишней. Т.к. кнопка находится непосредственно внутри элемента с нужным классом.
    if(nearestWindow !== null && nearestWindow.hasClass('.opened'))
        nearestWindow.removeClass('.opened');
});
```

Comment: выложил полную версию одного из множества таких окошек. Вероятно, поэтому ваш ответ не срабатывает

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Сделал по вашему принципу